# Error: Unicode character ​ (U+200B)

Tags: symbols, unicode, input, input-encodings, characters

I'm getting this error

```
marcoteorico.tex
31
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ​ (U+200B)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.31 ... ciencias de la computación, un grafo
```

I already checked another post but I didn't find the solution for my problem... they talk about ZERO WIDTH SPACE) but I don't know where I'm using that...

this is marcoteorico.tex

```
\clearpage
\section{Marco Teorico}\label{sec:mt}

\subsection{Programación Paralela}

La programación paralela significa programar de tal manera que dividimos nuestro problema en fragmentos que luego se pueden procesar por separado y simultáneamente.

\subsubsection{¿Por qué paralelizar?}

La respuesta es simple, porque en muchos casos la paralelización nos proporciona una forma de utilizar recursos que estan disponibles para ser usados y que por efectuarse esto te genera un ahorro de tiempo y recursos.

El procesamiento de datos de matriz por bucles o nidos de bucles es un componente central en la mayoría de los códigos científicos. Un ejemplo típico son las operaciones de álgebra lineal en vectores o matrices. A menudo, los cálculos realizados en elementos de matriz individuales son independientes entre sí y, por lo tanto, son candidatos típicos para la ejecución paralela de varios procesadores en la memoria compartida

Esto se puede explicar con un ejemplo~\cite[p.~117]{paralelcomp}

En el ejemplo de la \textbf{Figura~\ref{fig:paralelismoej}} se muestra las dos caras de la moneda en la ejecucion de un codigo, la de la izquierda representa si se estuviera usando paralelismo y la derecha sin usarlo.
Al utilizar paralelismo en la multiplicacion de elementos de un vector se puede dividir el trabajo en dos partes para que cada proceso realice una parte durante el mismo instante de tiempo, asi el tiempo de trabajo que tomaria por un solo proceso realizar la actividad queda dividida.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{fotos/paralelismo.JPG}
    \caption{Ejemplo de paralelismo}
    \label{fig:paralelismoej}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

En la programación paralela los \Gls{procesadores} son nuestros heroes


\subsection{Grafos}
En matemáticas y ciencias de la computación, un grafo ​es un conjunto de objetos llamados vértices o nodos unidos por enlaces llamados aristas o arcos, que permiten representar relaciones binarias entre elementos de un conjunto.\\

Podemos elegir entre dos formas estándar para representar un grafo G=(V,E) como una colección de listas de adyacencia o como una matriz de adyacencia.\cite[p.~610]{alghoritms}

\subsection{Deep First Search}

%\acrlong{dfs} or \acrshort{dfs}
El \acrfull{dfs} o en español Búsqueda de profundidad primero, es un algoritmo para atravesar o buscar estructuras de datos de árbol o grafos. El algoritmo comienza en el nodo raíz (seleccionando algún nodo arbitrario como nodo raíz en el caso de un grafo) y explora lo más lejos posible a lo largo de cada rama antes de retroceder.

\subsection{Ordenamiento Topologico}


En ciencias de la computación, un orden topológico u ordenamiento topológico de un grafo dirigido es un ordenamiento lineal de sus vértices de tal manera que por cada arista dirigida uv desde el vértice u al vértice v, se encuentra antes de v en el ordenamiento. Por ejemplo, los vértices del gráfico pueden representar tareas a realizar, y los bordes pueden representar restricciones de que una tarea debe realizarse antes que otra; en esta aplicación, un orden topológico es solo una secuencia válida para las tareas. Es posible un ordenamiento topológico si y solo si el grafo no tiene ciclos dirigidos, es decir, si es un grafo \acrfull{dag}. Cualquier DAG tiene al menos un orden topológico, y se conocen algoritmos para construir un orden topológico de cualquier DAG en tiempo lineal.\\

Un ejemplo de esto se ilustra en la \textbf{Figura~\ref{fig:topoorder}} ~\cite[p.~613]{alghoritms} en el que una persona ordena topologicamente su ropa cuando se viste.
Cada borde dirigido (u,v) significa que la prenda u debe ponerse antes de la prenda v. Los tiempos de la busqueda de profundidad DFS se muestran junto a cada vértice.
en la Figura b) se muestra el mismo grafo que a) ordenado topológicamente, con sus vértices dispuestos de izquierda a derecha en orden decreciente de tiempo de finalización. Todas las aristas dirigidas van de izquierda a derecha.
Este grafico mustra que por lo tanto la persona no podría ponerse primero el cinturon sin antes haberse puesto la polera.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{fotos/topoorder.JPG}
    \caption{Ejemplo orden topologico}
    \label{fig:topoorder}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

and according texwork this are line 30,31

```
30\subsection{Grafos}
31En matemáticas y ciencias de la computación, un grafo​es un conjunto de objetos llamados vértices o nodos unidos por enlaces llamados aristas o arcos, que permiten representar relaciones binarias entre elementos de un conjunto.\\
```

and this is my main page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel} % espanol
\decimalpoint
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz} %era para hacer los grafos pero no investigué mucho asi que lo hice con word
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%Header an Footer Stuff

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }

%


%Hyperlink
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}
%

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Código}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Códigos}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{teal!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{olive!40!black},
  stringstyle=\color{gray},
}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\color{red}$\hookrightarrow$\space},
}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{algoritmos}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Índice de \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms





\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\input{glosario}

\input{acronimo}




\begin{document}

\input{portada}

%Este es la tabla de contenido
\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{empty} %oculta el numero de pagina
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\cleardoublepage  sirve para ar un salto creo
\lstlistoflistings

\input{resumen}

\input{introduccion}

\input{marcoteorico}

\input{problema}




\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary

\input{apendice}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Bibliografia}
\bibliography{referencias}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200B}{I~AM~HERE!!!!}` in your preamble and then look where the text appears.

Comment: it is just before `es` in `grafo es` see https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?%20grafo%20%E2%80%8Bes%20un%20conjunto

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and how can I solve that ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what does {I~AM~HERE!!!!} mean ?

Comment: just delete `grafo ​es un conjunto` and re-type it without invisible control characters.

Comment: The point of Ulrike's suggestion is to define the character so that it makes some visible text (any visible text) so that you can see more clearly where it is so know where to delete it.